# How does Firebase Dynamic Links store and retrieve DeepLink information when the app is installed from the Store?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a question about Firebase Dynamic Links.
When an app is not installed and is installed from the Store via a DynamicLinks, I believe that the DeepLink information can be retrieved in the installed app using the DynamicLinks SDK. But where is the DeepLink information stored when you tap on a DynamicLink, and how does the DynamicLinks SDK retrieve this DeepLink information? (I also think that the same can be done on iOS, so I'd like to know the equivalent mechanism for iOS.)

Answer (score 3):

On Android, the deep link is copied to the Android clipboard and the FDL SDK later retrieves it from the clipboard after the app is installed. On iOS, the deep link is stored on FDL servers and the FDL SDK retrieves the link from the servers after the app in installed.

Hope that helps!